# Why does SQL Server use .bak extension?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I've googled and I can't find any information about it. I'm wondering why does SQL Server uses .bak extensions by default.

I know that there are a lot of different software which use .bak extension, not only SQL Server.

And another question, is there any other file formats that can be used for the backup file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of backup software, you can't use anybody's bak file interchangeably. SQL Server's backup file format is proprietary to SQL Server. It doesn't work for other apps.

You can also name your backups anything you want during the backup process - you could use the .docx extension, for example, but that doesn't mean they're readable in Microsoft Word.

(Some folks default their differential backups to .diff, and log backups to .log - but other folks just name 'em all .bak. There's no real standard out there, and changing the extension doesn't affect the contents.)

Comment: I like to use .BKP for full, .DIFF for differential and .log for log files. it keeps things more organized.

Comment: @Brent Ozar Thanks! Are there other backup formats, or all SQL Server database backups are made in .bak format with different extensions?

Comment: @PaulNiko the actual format is initially called "Microsoft Tape Format" which is just a physical formatting structure. The actual backup formatting inside of MTF data streams AFAIK are not formally documented. Much as Brent said you can name it whatever you like but the format header of the file will all show it's in an MTF format. Additionally these internal formats may and do change between versions.